# Initial and final period must contains a date and not contains in other date

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have this model:

```
public class Documento
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public int CustomerId {get;set;}
   public int DocumentTypeId {get;set;}
   public DateTime Date {get;set;} //issuance of the document
   public DateTime NextDate {get;set;} //will be valid
}
```

The `Date` property means the date the document was generated and the `NextDate` property is the date on which the document needs to be regenerated

Data sample

```
Id  -  CustomerId  -  DocumentTypeId           Date       -      NextDate
1   -  1           -     1              -  12/12/2017     -     12/12/2018 - Generate in 2017, expiring in 2018
2   -  1           -     1              -  12/12/2018     -     12/12/2019 - Generate in 2018, this ok
3   -  1           -     1              -  10/01/2017     -     10/01/2018
```

I need to search documents that were not generated in 2018

My starting date is `01/01/2018` and final `01/01/2019`

I tried this:

```
db.Documents.AsNoTracking().AsQueryable()
                       .Where(x =>
                            DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.Date) >= model.Start &&
                            DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.Date) <= model.End &&
                            DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.NextDate) >= model.Start &&
                            DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.NextDate) <= model.End).ToList();
```

[Edit]

When initial and final date is passed 
`01/01/2018` and `01/01/2019` the return corret is:

```
Id  -  CustomerId  -  DocumentTypeId           Date       -      NextDate
3   -  1           -     1              -  10/01/2017     -     10/01/2018
```

Document with `(Id 1)` was generate in 2017 and valid until 2018. But in 12/12/2018 was regenerated `(Id 2)`

Comment: _"I need to get all that is expired this year, but validating if it has already been done"_ - How are "expired" and "done" defined?

Comment: Where is ```Type``` defined in the model?  I also don't quite understand the heading or the question "Initial and final period must contains a date(Property NextDate) and not contains in other date (Property Date)".  Can you elaborate in the question?

Comment: I think you need to clear up some of your terminology, especially since these words don't map to any class properties. What is "initial period"? What is "final period"? What is "expired"? What is "done"?

Comment: It would also help if you provided sample input and expected output data. And what specifically isn't working with the code that you tried?

Comment: @stuartd NextDate is a property for next create document

Comment: @MichaelPuckettII sorry, ignore this property

Comment: I edit this question

Comment: Your question is posted clean and easy to read, so good job there; but the question itself is a bit confusing.  Nothing should be assumed when writing the question; we have no idea what you're doing or what the wording means.  I feel confident someone can help you solve this issue but I don't believe we truly understand the issue.  Can you edit it some more with maybe what you have and what you want?  I'm a little lost trying to understand it.

Comment: @MichaelPuckettII I edit now

Comment: Out of the 3 dates you have listed; which one are you wanting to get back in return?  I think that's the confusion.  Are you expecting Id 3 to be returned only?

Comment: You also said you need to search documents that were not generated in 2018 but the dates overlap.  So can it not end in 2018 also?  Right now you're looking for dates that both start in 2018 and expire in 2018;  If it started in 2018 and is good for a year then it will expire in 2019 and your search will not find those.

Comment: Yes, only ID 3 because is unique that not generate in 2018

Comment: Ok, well Id 3 expires in 2018 and your search says, it can expire in 2018 but not start in 2018.  Let's use 2018 as the constant; if you want to find documents that are expiring in 2018 only then that's one thing.  If you want to find documents that expire in 2018 or earlier that's another.  Let me try to work it out.

Comment: I want document that are expiring in 2018 using a Property NextDate. But ID 2 already generate this year

Comment: So you want Id 1 and Id 3 returned not just Id 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to understand exactly what you want to do here, but what I understood is that in order to validate this model, the `Date` property needs to be before `model.Start`, and the `NextDate` property needs to be between `model.Start` and `model.End`

To achieve this, you need to change your LINQ query:

```
db.Documents.AsNoTracking().AsQueryable()
                       .Where(x => x.Type == model.Type &&
                            DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.Date) < model.Start &&
                            DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.NextDate) >= model.Start &&
                            DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.NextDate) <= model.End).ToList();
```

The LINQ query you currently have is checking that both the `Date` and `NextDate` properties fall in between `model.Start` and `model.End`

I would also suggest changing the property names from "Date" and "NextDate" to something more meaningful. Property names should be self-explanatory whenever possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the documents that expired in 2018 then I'm assuming you only need to look at the end dates.

This query will find documents that have a `NextDate` that falls within your search.
Note: I used `let` to avoid redundant calls to `DbFunctions.TruncateTime`.

```
var expiredDocuments = from document in db.Documents.AsNoTracking().AsQueryable()
                       let endDate = DbFunctions.TruncateTime(document.NextDate)
                       where endDate >= model.Start && endDate <= model.End
                       select document;
```

Comment: Thanks. I want expired in 2018 but not exists in property Date

Comment: This returns Id 1 and Id 3 and both expire in 2018. Both also have 2017 Date. I apologize but what you want is not understood.

Comment: Hi Michael, The ID2 is representing that the document was already generated in 2018 for that particular customer